# Low resolution caused by No valid modes for "DFP-0" - Mint-17 NVidia

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia

I don't seem to be able to configure xorg.conf to increase my monitors resolution (currently running at 1280x800).  I've been working on this for several hours.  I'm new at all this, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

- Monitor: A single monitor - Dell 3007wfp and I can normally run it at 2560x1600
- Video Card: Nvidia 300 NVS
- OS: Mint 17
- Driver: nvidia-340.96-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

I figure the video card should at least support 2048x1280!  I copied the modeline from the `cvt 2048 1280` output.

I've followed several tutorials started with the `xorg.conf` produced by sudo nvidia-xconfig and configured the following sections:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "3007WFP"
    VendorName     "DELL"
    Modeline       "2048x1280_60.00"  220.25  2048 2192 2408 2768  1280 1283 1289 1327 -hsync +vsync
    ModelName      "3007WFP"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "3007WFP"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "2048x1280"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But when I look at the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I see:

```
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on NVS 300 at PCI:5:0:0
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0) (boot, connected)
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.704] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[     6.705] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 480.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     6.705] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[     6.705] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device DELL 3007WFP (DFP-0) (Using EDID frequencies has
[     6.705] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[     6.705] (WW) NVIDIA(0): No valid modes for "DFP-0:2048x1280"; removing.
[     6.705] (WW) NVIDIA(0): 
[     6.705] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to validate any modes; falling back to the default mode
[     6.705] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select".
[     6.705] (WW) NVIDIA(0): 
[     6.705] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     6.705] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[     6.705] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1280 x 800
[     6.744] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (50, 50); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     6.744] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[     6.744] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     6.744] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[     6.789] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
```

- If I use the `Option "UseEDID" "False"`  Then I get a blank screen.
- Also if I include the modeline for 1280x800 in the config and ask it for that mode, I get the same error but when it uses automatic mode it resolves to 1280x800?

If this forum is not the right place for this kind of question please refer me to somewhere else, I'll be more than happy to delete my question.

Comment: I got passed the No valid modes by including another option: Option "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes".  But now I get a blank screen